# DateTime trying to set AM/PM for the Date

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, output

Can someone please help me set the last part of the date AM/PM part. I am using C# project and here is what I have so far:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 00, 00, 00);
or
new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 11, 59, 59);
```

Where do I set AM or PM

Because when I try to print the DateTime out with the following:

```
 startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss tt")
```

I get

```
06/13/14 00:00:00 AM 
06/16/14 11:59:59 AM
```

Why I get AM in both cases??? Any advice or improvements on the coder a better way to do this.

I want to set the DateTime and then manually add PM or AM part.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I will go with DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 59

Comment: I think you can't do this, since its not ISO date time format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to set the time manually in this case:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

Also, make sure you're not doing this from an ASP.Net web application.  The "now" or "today" of your web server is probably not the same as that of the person viewing your website.  [More on this here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

Comment: I like this. Very clever!

Comment: Also, you didn't say *why* you wanted 23:59:59. It's often better to use midnight on the next day and just use `<` instead of `<=`.  You don't want to exclude 23:59:59.123.

Answer (score 3):

"AM" and "PM" are part of the display formatting, they're not *set* on the data itself.  Notice the times you're setting:

```
... 00, 00, 00 ...
... 11, 59, 59 ...
```

Both of these times are AM times.  One is midnight, the other is one second before noon.

If you want noon or 11:59:59 *PM* then you need to set the hour as 12 or 23 instead:

```
... 12, 00, 00 ...
... 23, 59, 59 ...
```

Then the output formatting where you ask for a 12-hour display will display the time you're looking for.

Times are stored without any human-readable formatting.  At a low level, they're just integers.  Slightly higher level, they're 24-hour days.  Nothing actually *stores* time in a 12-hour format.  That's just a display concern.